# How can I make this function wait for a the JSON data to be ready

Tags: android, json, api, flutter

I am trying to make ***initialVideoId*** wait for ***keyy*** function wait but I don't know how to go about.

I am working with Flutter and my job is to get the video key from TMDB but don't know how to make ***initialVideoId*** to wait for the JSON data to be ready before accessing it.

```
  getVideoUrl() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${widget.movieId}/videos?api_key=$kApiKey');

    // print(json.decode(response.body));

    String data = response.body;
    // data.length;

    var keyy = jsonDecode(data)['results'][0]['key'];
    // results[0].key
    print(keyy);
  
  }

  // String link = 'e9waCtSVoZ0';

  YoutubePlayerController _controller;
  bool isPlaerReady = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    print(widget.movieId);
    getVideoUrl();
    // _controller = YoutubePlayerController(initialVideoId: keyy);
    this._controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: keyy,
      flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
        mute: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        disableDragSeek: true,
        loop: false,
        isLive: false,
        // forceHideAnnotation: true,
        forceHD: false,
        enableCaption: true,
      ),
    )..addListener(_videoPlayerListner);
  }

  void _videoPlayerListner() {
    print(_controller.value.playerState.toString());
  }

void isPlayReady(){

}
  @override
  void deactivate() {
    _controller.pause();
    super.deactivate();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return Text(getVideoUrl());
    // 
      return YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        topActions: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(width: 8.0),
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              _controller.metadata.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18.0,
              ),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 1,
            ),
          ),
        ],
        onReady: () {
          isPlaerReady;
        },
        onEnded: (data) {},
      );
  }
}
```

I added my build method to the question as requested

Comment: Can you add `build` method of your class to the question?

Comment: You can call the getVideoUrl() inside a FutureBuilder widget and then with the response, do whatever you need

Comment: @Stel can you explain better? I am quiet new to flutter

Comment: @fartem I have done that

Comment: FutureBuilder is a widget the you can call a function that return a Future (something that will be resolved) and with tah result you can build something in your screen. You can read more about it here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: @Stel the problem I am facing is how I can make `initialVideoId` to wait for the JSON data.

Comment: @Rex your YoutubePlayerController will be inside the builder part of the FutureBuilder, and your Future part will call the getVideoUrl method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a FutureBuilder as suggested to do this.

For example you can do a function to get the video key like this:

```
Future getVideoKey() async {
  var result = await http.get('https://getkeyfromTMDB');
  return result;    
}
```

then when you get your result call the build method for your widget. This is an example based on your code and it might not work out of the box:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    future: getVideoKey(), //this line is important. this tells your app to wait for the response before building the ui.
    return FutureBuilder(
            future: getVideoKey(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return YoutubePlayer(
                  controller: _controller,
                  showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
                  progressIndicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  topActions: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 8.0),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        _controller.metadata.title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  onReady: () {
                    isPlaerReady;
                  },
                  onEnded: (data) {},
                );
              } else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            });
  }
```

Comment: you didn't say how initialVideoId will get it's data

Comment: You just put all the code you already have for initialVideoId in the getVideoKey() function. Not much else needed. What this does is that your app will wait for getVideoKey() to get the response, complete the initialization (in your case the controller) then build the ui.